# Kotlin: Variable 'result' must be initialized

Tags: kotlin

The compiler is showing error Kotlin: Variable `result` must be initialized.

Here is the code.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    print("Enter two numbers: ")

    // nextDouble() reads the next double from the keyboard
    var first= readLine()!!.toDouble()
    var second = readLine()!!.toInt()

    print("Enter an choice(1-4)): ")
    val operator = readLine()!!.toInt()

    var result: Double

    when (operator) {
        1 -> result = first + second
        2 -> result = first - second
        3 -> result = first * second
        4 -> result = first / second

        else -> {
            println("Error.")
        }
    }

    println("The result is :- " +result)
}
```

Answer (score 11):

The problem is that when you read the value of `result` here:

```
println("The result is :- " +result)
```

`result` might not be initialized, because here:

```
var result: Double

when (operator) {
    1 -> result = first + second
    2 -> result = first - second
    3 -> result = first * second
    4 -> result = first / second

    else -> {
        println("Error.")
    }
```

You are NOT assigning a value to `result` in the `else` branch. You have several options, one could be to make `result` nullable. For instance:

```
var result = when (operator) {
    1 -> first + second
    2 -> first - second
    3 -> first * second
    4 -> first / second
    else -> null
}

if (result != null) {
    println("The result is :- " + result)
} else {
    println("Error.")
}
```

Notice that if the operator is not (1-4) the value of `result` will be `null`. Also, in your code you're printing "Error" and then again you're attempting to print the result.

To add something more, you could make the thing a bit nicer if you defined your operator with the `when` statement as a method reference:

```
print("Enter an choice(1-4)): ")
val operatorCode = readLine()!!.toInt()

val operator: ((Int) -> Double)? = when (operatorCode) {
    1 -> first::plus
    2 -> first::minus
    3 -> first::times
    4 -> first::div
    else -> null
}

if (operator != null) {
    val result = operator.invoke(second)
    println("The result is :- " + result)
} else {
    println("Error.")
}
```

Answer (score 6):

As jrtapsell points out the main issue is that you declare result to be a Double but you since you don't cover every possible value in the when statement, you are accessing an un-initialized variable.

Another option, if you really operators other than 1-4 want it to be an error condition and don't want result to end up with a valid Double is to use Optionals.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    print("Enter two numbers: ")

    // nextDouble() reads the next double from the keyboard
    var first= readLine()!!.toDouble()
    var second = readLine()!!.toInt()

    print("Enter an choice(1-4)): ")
    val operator = readLine()!!.toInt()

    var result: Double? = null  

    when (operator) {
        1 -> result = first + second
        2 -> result = first - second
        3 -> result = first * second
        4 -> result = first / second

        else -> {
            println("Error.")
        }
    }

    // only print the result if not null
    result?.let {
        println("The result is :- " +result)
    }
}
```

In this case result will be null if the operator is not one of 1-4.

Answer (score 2):

## What is the error message trying to tell you

> Variable 'result' must be initialized.

This means there are paths through your code where you access `result` before you have given it a value.

This is a problem because it means you have probably missed off handling a condition.

## How do you get through your code without setting result

If the user inputs 5 result is not set

## How to fix

Either set result in the else branch, or give it a default value in the declaration